# Error in Adding the In-app Billing Library

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, google-play-services

I was doing this following these steps as mentioned in the [link](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html).

1. Copy the `IInAppBillingService.aidl` file to your Android project.
   (1) If you are using Eclipse: Import the `IInAppBillingService.aidl` file into your /src    directory.
   (2) If you are developing in a non-Eclipse environment: Create the following directory /src/com/android/vending/billing and copy the `IInAppBillingService.aidl` file into this directory.
2. Build your application. You should see a generated file named `IInAppBillingService.java` in the `/gen` directory of your project.
3. Add the helper classes from the `/util` directory of the `TrivialDrive` sample to your project. Remember to change the package name declarations in those files accordingly so that your project compiles correctly.

But when I finished that, Eclipse gives me an error:

```
interface IInAppBillingService should be declared in a file called com\android\vending\billing\IInAppBillingService.aidl.
```

the `aidl` file is in the correct directory, but the  `IInAppBillingService.java` file was not generated.

Has anybody seen that before?

Comment: Better to clean your project once... While cleaning IInAppBillingService.java file in /gen rebuilds

Comment: @joshwoodward -- I had luck by sequentially adding each successive folder com then android then vending then billing.  Then I could place the aidl file into the billing folder and get generation.

Comment: I was having the same problem, in Eclipse. I went to Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source, removed the /src dir and then added it again. I think I created this problem by adding /gen after /src. By removing /src while leaving /gen there, and then adding /src back, it seemed to fix things. But that could be blind luck ;)

Comment: maybe you put the file to src root folder. I make the same mistake too.

Answer (score 57):

right click on the head of the project and create  a new PACKAGE ... call the package com.android.vending.billing ....drop the aidl file in there to quiet the error.

Some food for thought: for those with an interest - when using someone's aidl file, the package name for both apps must be the same.  google used com.android.vending.billing as their package name for their billing aidl interface, so you MUST also use the same package name in your app. This is the rule when using aidl.

Comment: I don't understand why people@google(android) spread information just like this and do not concentrate everything linked at one page or group of page. Here is where they put all detailed explanation about your issue @j2emanue [Detailed google play billing explanations](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html)

Comment: I had no typo, but deleting the package and pasting this exactly worked.

Answer (score 29):

For android studio users, this should be the structure:

[image]

[Worked for me, according to this answer.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56755)

Comment: this worked for me, but i found it easier to do via Windows Explorer / Mac Finder than via Studio

Comment: this worked if not just clean the project and do the import (alt + enter)

Comment: This answer **plus** cleaning project helped me.

Answer (score 4):

The structure that [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038702/david) mentioned works fine in Android Studio 1.2.

Your path for the billing folder should look like:

```
[YOUR_APP_FOLDER]/app/src/main/aidl/com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService.aidl
```

This is where you can check the IInAppBillingService.java generated file:

```
[YOUR_APP_FOLDER]/app/build/generated/source/aidl/debug/com/android/vending/IInAppBillingService.java
```

Good luck !

Answer (score 2):

In the /src directory, click File > New > Package, then create a package named com.android.vending.billing

Copy the IInAppBillingService.aidl file from /extras/google/play_billing/ and paste it into the src/com.android.vending.billing/ folder in your workspace.

Build your application. You should see a generated file named IInAppBillingService.java in the /gen directory of your project.

Answer (score 1):

The only advice I can give you is to re-check spelling of the directories in your src folder, if you put the file into /src/com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService.aidl it should work

Answer (score 1):

The other suggestions are good. Sometimes eclipse may just be weird though, and a project clean can fix it in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I did what @j2emanue suggested (click New/Package, add "com.android.vendor.billing"), and I also added that directories to my file system (com/android/vendor/billing) then copied the file in it. Then, clicked Refresh on the project. Build, and it succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have added billing library in your build.gladle under dependencies

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1'
}
```

See the last line in the above code. Implementing 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1' solved same problem for me

Answer (score 0):

2018

```
app/build.gradle:

sourceSets {
  main {
    aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/aidl']
  }
}
```

or

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
  }
}
```

for `IInAppBillingService.aidl`