# Where do I put "IInAppBillingService.aidl" in a LibGDX project?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, in-app-purchase

I've been trying to get IAP to work with my LibGDX game for Android for over 6 hours. First I tried to use gdx-pay, but sadly the documentation for it is very unclear to me and was therefore not able to get it to work.
  Because my games are only for Android (for now) gdx-pay was overkill anyway, so I decided to directly implement Google Play IAP. I found [a tutorial](http://pipplo.com/libgdx-google-in-app-billing-v3/) that is pretty clear, but sadly it doesn't explain where I should put the IInAppBillingService.aidl file.

I tried putting it in a newly created directory in the Android directory, namely /android/vending/billing, but that doesn't seem to work and the directory also doesn't show when I have my project view on Android. 
   I also tried creating a new package "andoird.vending.billing" in the java directory where the game package with the AndroidLauncher is in but that doesn't work either.
  With both these methods I'm not able to import the class IabHelper in the following tutorial code which is in AndroidLauncher.java located in my game's package:

```
    String base64EncodedPublicKey = "xxx";

    // compute your public key and store it in base64EncodedPublicKey
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                Log.d("IAB", "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
            }
            // Hooray, IAB is fully set up!
            Log.d("IAB", "Billing Success: " + result);
        }
    });
```

Where (and how) am I supposed to put the "IInAppBillingService.aidl" file to be able to import the IabHelper class in my LibGDX project? If you have a clearer tutorial on gdx-pay or on a technique similar to the one I'm using now I would also appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927759/error-in-adding-the-in-app-billing-library

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was gone last week, so sorry for my late response. I already found that post, but I am using LibGDX which has a different folder structure. I also don't know how to make those blue folders. Do you happen to know how I can do that?